# Visual Studio 2015: How to automate cmake operations?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, cmake, vtk

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Edition. I followed this tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IgvbhyDh8r0

Like Visual Studio creates a .sln file when any new project is saved and then on building it executes it to build the project, in the case of this VTK tutorial, it uses CMake to create the build file .sln for Visual studio to execute. Is there any way I can automate/replace the process of CMake using Visual Studio only?

PS- Just ignore if I have any misunderstanding of the concepts as I'm totally new to this and was not able to find proper documentation on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you've generated a `.sln` file once, you don't need to run CMake manually again. It hooks itself into ZERO_CHECK project, so it would regenerate the solution every time you change `CMakeLists.txt`.

But you can't do with VS only, as you have to generate `.sln` for the first time.

Comment: So how would you recommend me to proceed if I already have a VS project but on the way I need VTK which can be built using CMake?

Comment: I'd advice you to configure VTK with `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` set to somethink like `C:\vtk` and then building generated `INSTALL` project. Then, in your own project add `C:\vtk` to additional include paths and use VTK libraries from there.

Comment: `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` doesn't work, even after specifying a different path. While building the make file generated by CMake, it creates 2 folders (bin and lib) inside the build folder specified to CMake where there's a Debug folder created in each which contains all the dll and lib files respectively. Is there any problem with the configuration I make with the CMake?

Comment: @HarshitAgrawal What makefile? Aren't you using Visual Studio generator?

Comment: I apologize as I didn't read ur instructions carefully. I successfully did what u instructed. After adding path to additional include and lib directories in Project>Properties>VC++ Directories and adding system path to C:\vtk\bin, I'm getting multiple LNK2019 errors in Visual Studio. Anything which I've missed?

Comment: I discovered that I had not added the linker to the required libraries... Anyways, thanks a lot for bearing with me...